# Simple Javascript bookmarklet question

Tags: javascript, url, bookmarklet, flickr

First, I know very little about writing code or javascript - so be gentle.  I had used a JavaScript bookmarklet (essentially a bookmark that would run simple code) in Firefox, because I'm lazy, to jump to the large size of an image in Flickr.

Example: going to a Flickr image you would get a URL that looked like this - http://www.flickr.com/photos/aloudnoise/5626322378/

The bookmarklet I had, that I cobbled together as a series of best guesses, was -

```
javascript:(function(){%20location.href%20=%20location.href%20+%20'sizes/l/';%20})();
```

This simply added "sizes/l/" to the end of the URL and saved me a couple of extra clicks.

Now, when you click on an image in Flickr the returned URL looks like this -
http://www.flickr.com/photos/aloudnoise/5626322378/in/photostream

This broke my bookmarklet, as clicking it now appends the url to "/in/photostream/sizes/l/" which is not a valid Flickr URL.

I'd like to change the bookmarklet to simply replace "/in/photosteam" with "/sizes/l/"

Note: on an ethical note, the "sizes/l/" simply loads the large size of the image, if available and if ALLOWED by the uploader, it is not meant to, nor does it, side-step an uploaders settings in flickr.  As I indicated, it just eliminates having to deal with a drop down box and a few extra clicks.

Comment: Java has applets. I wasn't aware that JavaScript had applets.

Comment: Are you looking for the term *[bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)*?

Comment: The word you're looking for is "bookmarklet"

Comment: Ha, You are correct.  Perhaps the media saturation of the term "app" has effected me.  No wonder there wasn't an app for that...  Had I remembered the term, I no doubt could have successfully searched for the answer.  At any rate, thanks for the quick reply and an answer that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
javascript:(function(){location.href=location.href.replace('/in/photostream', '/sizes/l/')})();
```

Comment: @valpospe: hurray! Delighted to help.