# Javascript bookmarklet to remove a portion of url

Tags: javascript, url, flickr

I would greatly appreciate any help with a script that I intend to run by clicking a bookmark that will remove the end part of a flickr url.

I presently have the following code

```
javascript:(function(){location.href=location.href.replace('/in/photostream', '/')})();
```

I based what I have with the code I found on the following page:[Simple Javascript bookmarklet question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691045/simple-javascript-bookmarklet-question/5691060#5691060)

So lets say I start on the following url
https://www.flickr.com/photos/nasacommons/7651153916/in/set-72157630766688018

I want to end at https://www.flickr.com/photos/nasacommons/7651153916/

Now since flickr uses many different location references after the image url other than just '/in/photostream' I am looking to have the code replace '/in/' and everything that follows it with just '/'

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This :-

```
location.href = location.href.substring(0,location.href.indexOf("in"));
```

---

OR

```
location.href = location.href.substring(0,location.href.lastIndexOf("in"));
```